# redis lua debugger -- why can't I print ARGV

Tags: lua, redis

I am trying a very simple lua script in the debug mode, and to inspect the ARGV.

```
local jobExists = redis.call('exists', ARGV[1])
if jobExists then 
  return false
end
```

And, I run the the debugger as below:

```
redis-cli --ldb --eval ./is_running.lua 0 , user:root
```

I am able to access the value of ARGV[1] within the program and it works fine.  But when I try to print, it says 'no such variable'.

```
lua debugger> print ARGV[1]
No such variable.
lua debugger>
```

So, it doesn't seem to be a lua table or array.  When I print ARGV instead of ARGV[1], i get the following output

```
lua debugger> print ARGV
<value> {"user:root"}
```

So, is this a limitation of the debugger, or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're NOT doing anything wrong.**

With lua debuger, you can only *print* the value of the whole `table` (`ARGV` is, in fact, a lua `table`), and you CANNOT only *print* an item of the `table`.

When you type the following command in the debuger:

`print varname`

Redis searches lua variables to find if there's a variable named `varname`. If it finds one, Redis prints the value of the variable. However, if there's no one named `varname`, it prints *No such variable*.

In your case, `print ARGV[1]` makes Redis try to find a variable, whose name is **exactly** *ARGV[1]*, and there's no such a variable, i.e. `strcmp("ARGV[1]", "ARGV") != 0`. So you get *No such variable*.

On the other hand, with `print ARGV`, Redis can find a (global) variable, whose name is exactly *ARGV*. So it prints the value the variable: all elements in the `table`.